# Google cloud service failed to trigger build found no logs

Tags: flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I'm trying to learn API service deployment on Google Cloud service for the first time.

First, backgrounds to the problem I am facing.
I have been following this particular tutorial posted on medium about deploying a Python FLASK API on Google Cloud service.

Link: https://medium.com/google-cloud/deploy-a-python-flask-server-using-google-cloud-run-d47f728cc864

I have cloned the project files from https://github.com/bbachi/python-flask-restapi.git into my own GitHub repository as instructed in the tutorial.

I managed to run flask locally without dockerized container and with dockerized container and confirmed that I could obtain JSON responses as intended from localhost.

Now I am at the part where I am connecting the GitHub address to the Google source repository and
create a cloud service that performs continuous deployment from the source repository.

The issue is that when I try to launch cloud build from the console page to start servicing, the repository
fails to build, showing no build logs as well.

[image]

When I access the service url "https://pythonrestapi-iltf7gaysq-du.a.run.app/", default error page appears
and states that repository has failed to build and deploy, further instructing me to troubleshoot based on checking build logs, however build history page of the console shows no logs at all, and I am frankly very lost on how to fix this issue and also unable to fully grasp what I can do for this situation, as I am new in google cloud services and in the general area of backend as well.

If I can know the solution for the current problem, or a reliable method to properly troubleshoot this issue, it will be greatly appreciated.

Some things I have done previously trying to fix it on my own accord:

1. Made sure I enabled the following API services for the current project:

   - Compute engine API
   - Cloud Storage
   - Cloud Datastore API
   - Cloud Deployment Manager V2API
2. Created a service account with a owner privilege and granted it to myself (designated to my own google account I use to access the project console)

All deployment process was performed on the web console, not the Google SDK cli.

This is my first time posting a question on Stack Overflow, so the post might not be as informative as
you normally expect. If you need further information or any sort of clarifications please tell me and I'll
provide them as best as I can.